# jQuery .nextAll() subset filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<ul>
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li class="block">list item 3</li>
   <li>list item 4</li>
   <li>list item 5</li>
   <li class="block">list item 6</li>
   <li>list item 7</li>
   <li>list item 8</li>
</ul>
```

How would you collect **items 4 and 5 only**?

`$('li.block').nextAll()` of course returns items 4 though 8, including 6.

I'm wondering what's the best way to do this. Some ugly `$.each()` loop on the `li's` with a filter function sounds depressingly complicated. I'm hoping for a selector-only way... and fail so far.

Comment: You want to select elements between the first `.block` and the next `.block`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is probably what you're after.

```
$('li.block').first().nextUntil('.block');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMm7z/).

Comment: Ah. That's what I love about SO. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption, but this works:

```
$('li.block')
    .first()
    .nextUntil(".block")
    .css("background-color","yellow")
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gvwwy/2/

Comment: Doesn't this also return items 7 and 8? The OP asked for only items 4 and 5.

Comment: Oops, sorry you're right.  I misread the part for what he wanted!  Editing answer...

Comment: can't accept multiple answers, but I figured at least I can +1 this